# MySQL lock compatibility

Tags: mysql, locking

According to the official docs from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html):

the lock compatibility matrix:

```
    X              IX          S         IS
X   Conflict    Conflict    Conflict    Conflict
IX  Conflict    Compatible  Conflict    Compatible
S   Conflict    Conflict    Compatible  Compatible
IS  Conflict    Compatible  Compatible  Compatible
```

The docs also say:

> Thus, intention locks do not block anything except full table requests
>   (for example, LOCK TABLES ... WRITE). The main purpose of IX and IS
>   locks is to show that someone is locking a row, or going to lock a row
>   in the table.

If the intention locks only block full table requests, then how to explain the IX conflicts with S lock in the above lock compatibility matrix? To my understanding, the S and X in the lock compatibility matrix are both record locks, it's that right?

Answer (score 0):

> To my understanding, the S and X in the lock compatibility matrix are both record locks, it's that right?

That is correct. Incorrect is the assumption that you can directly compare table and record locks, which the documentation probably does not make completely clear, and the part "These rules can be conveniently summarized by means of the following lock type compatibility matrix" might be a bit misleading, as it does not cover everything (namely any conflict information about `S`/`X`-*table* locks with *record* locks).

Technically, that matrix defines the result when checking locks on some object, e.g. whenever MySQL tries to add a lock to something. If you try to get an `S` lock on a table, it would conflict with an `IX` lock on that table.

If a record could have an intention lock, it would conflict there too. Just because a lockable object doesn't use intention locks doesn't change the (general) compatibility matrix.

Technically, the internal datatype for locks is the same for records and tables, the intention locks are just never set for records. A record lock will actually never be compared to a table lock (as these are two different objects), and the only reason a record lock interferes with a table lock is the locking protocol (which requires a lock on both the table and the record to lock a record).

So to lock a record, you will typically require a *different* table lock. The compatibity matrix is the same, but the value for the table can and usually will differ from the value of the record.

So

> Thus, intention locks do not block anything except full table requests (for example, LOCK TABLES ... WRITE).

is correct because only full table requests require a lock that conflicts with an existing intention lock, and records do not use intention locks. But to repeat it: you still have to compare tow different locks. An `S`-lock on a record cannot conflict with the lock on a table, as these two object will never be compared.

The manual is mixing table and record locks a bit. It actually defines `IS` and `IX` as:

> - Intention shared (IS): Transaction T intends to set S locks on individual rows in table t.
> - Intention exclusive (IX): Transaction T intends to set X locks on those rows.

so if you want, `IS` and `IX` in the matrix can somewhat be interpreted as properties of rows (which they technically are not), while you read them as the lock on the table (as it can only be set for a table, but which is a different lock). But the matrix still only describes the situation to compare *records* (which the manual probably does not make clear enough), and it *does not* include any compatibility information with an `S` or `X` *table* lock.

So to summarize: you do not need "to explain the IX conflicts with S lock in the above lock compatibility matrix", as it simply does not cover that situation.

Comment: 1. `S` and `X` lock only row-level lock or they can be table-level and row-level. 2. You say it is correct for `To my understanding, the S and X in the lock compatibility matrix are both record locks, it's that right?`, so you mean `S` and `X` are row-level lock in MySQL doc about lock compatibility matrix, right? Because in my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50484570/mysql-lock-confusion/), Vatev said they are table-level lock in lock compatibility matrix, while you said they are row-level here.