# MySQL lock confusion

Tags: mysql

Mysql 5.6 Innodb repeatable-read isolation level.

```
T1                                        T2
select ... where id = 1 for update
                                          select ... where id = 1 for update
```

`T1` run first, then execute `T2`, they are in separate transactions.

The result is `select for update` of `T2` is blocked.

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html,
`select for update` will set `IX` lock on table, and `IX` is compatible with `IX` base on the lock compatibility matrix in this document.

***Then why 2nd `select for update` is blocked by 1st?***

I searched some posts about this question, now I also have following questions related with it:

1. `select for update` will set `IX` on table first, then set `X` on match index/row, right?
2. `X` and `S` lock can be table-level or row-level, right?
3. In lock type compatibility matrix of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html, the `X` and `S` means table-level lock, not row-level, right?
4. 2nd `select for update` blocked, because 1st `select for update` have set `IX` on table and `X` on matched index/row, so when 2nd `select for update` set `IX` on table, it is ok. But when it set `X` latter, it is blocked because it has been set `X` by 1st `select for update`, right?

Comment: Your edit sounds like you already figured (most of) it out already, you are right, there are are two different aspects (table and rows), which isn't 100% clear from the documentation (unless you already know how it works); I wrote an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48322262/6248528) where somewhere had a similar problem with that matrix (it might answer your follow up questions too). In general: T2 is supposed to wait, that is the correct behaviour, you just have to read the documentaton in a way that it fits.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks for your reply. I have some questions after reading you answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317009/mysql-lock-compatibility/48322262#48322262), It's appreciate if you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Then why 2nd select for update is blocked by 1st?" - because that is the whole point of having an exclusive(X) lock.

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. Yep.
4. Right.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer is what I want : use bullet points to say yes or no first, then explain the detail if you answer is no for each point. MySQL doc make me confusion since : 1. Maybe I have misunderstanding for the English doc which containing a lot of info 2. Its doc not clear at some point even misleading. Thus I am not sure my understanding is 100% correct. Hence I want to confirm my questions from talents like you who can make sure my questions.